# Styled `span` elements injected into comment output

Tags: comments, formatting

Does anyone know of a way to stop EE from injecting spans (with inline styles) into code blocks in comments? I'm fine with the `div` wrapping the `code` (that's not that big of a deal), but the spans are completely unnecessary.

Example output from EE:

```
<div class="codeblock">
    <code>
        <span style="color: #000000">
            <span style="color: #0000BB">This is code</span>
        </span>
    </code>
</div>
```

Edit to update: I've worked around this problem by using the following CSS to override the inline styles, so really this is just a matter of "I don't want junk in my markup" over broken functionality. (Also, a matter of pride, because `!important` is !embarassing.)

```
.codeblock code, .codeblock span {
    color: #ddd !important;
}
```

Comment: What editor are you using? Wygwam? EE Rich text?

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin that gives a WYSIWYG editor for BBCode (since we're talking comments, here). I can confirm that the editor isn't the issue, as the comment stored in the database is strictly `[code]This is code[/code]`.

Thanks for asking, though, as I was coming back here to add this bit of detail. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that EE doesn't do this. If it's in a code block then could it be some kind of syntax highlighting add-on or even a browser plugin? Do you have a URL we can see?

Comment: Nope, I can confirm that it is in the source code, not a DOM injection (browser plugin). Tested in multiple browsers on my machine, still happened. Also tested it in a BrowserStack instance (IE6, just for kicks) and it still occurred.

We have no highlighting add-ons installed. I even removed the one plugin that was wrapping the `{comment}` (the EE no_follow plugin), and it still happened.

Project isn't production-ready, so no shareable URL unfortunately. I'm confident this is a legit bug, so I'm going to file a ticket. I'll follow up here with anything that happens from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this EE bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19631/code-blocks-in-email-notifications-from-bugtracker-are-a-jumble-of-unformat): "...code tags are being parsed...[a]nd we add our own styling when that’s done."

So this is expected behavior, but overrideable with CSS:

```
.codeblock code, .codeblock span {
    color: [YOUR COLOR HERE] !important;
}
```